# Hide/show AChartEngine series using checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, achartengine, android-checkbox

Basically I have a chart with four different series, that by default shows all four of them at the same time. I want to allow the user to hide and/or show them again as he pleases by marking checkboxes.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640405/hide-show-series-in-achartengine) and followed both the advices given, but it didn't work. Here is what one of my checkboxes looks like now:

```
    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(distanceRenderer);
 //                 distanceRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#990000")); //(making transparent method)
            }
            else{
                //distanceRenderer.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //(making transparent method)
                multiRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(distanceRenderer);

            }
        }
    });
```

The idea is to when I uncheck the checkbox, I will hide that one renderer, when I check it again, it will be added again.

In the suggestions of the thread I linked to, they said to remove all renderers and then reenter the ones that aren't supposed to be hidden. I also tried this, but to no avail. The third option was simply to change the color to transparent whenever I wanted it to disappear, this also didn't work.

I debugged it, and it is getting in the conditions correctly, but nothing happens. Is there something I need to call that I've missed?

Thanks!

Edit: I don't know if this somehow helps, but I also tried to call the XYMultipleSeriesDataset's function repaint(). This caused an IllegalStateException, soooo.... Still no good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for hide purpose :

```
r.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mChartView.repaint();
```

where `r` is `XYSeriesRenderer` .

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I guess it didn't work before because I called the repaint() function whenever I was trying to add or remove the series... I wasn't being smart it enough to try it whenever I would change the color of my XYSeriesRenderer